# How to prevent output text of ipywidget from printing in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, ipython, ipywidgets

I am trying to graph a dataframe by variables with a variable selector to save space. However, when graphing, all the information from the previous selections is being printed.

I have tried:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets, Output
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
df['species'] = iris.target_names[iris.target]

text_output = Output()

def update_boxplot(variable):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    with text_output:
        display(widgets.Label(value=f"Variable: {variable}"))
    
    fig = px.box(df, x='species', y=variable,
                 title=f"Boxplot of {variable}",
                 labels={'species': 'Species', variable: variable})
    fig.show()

variable_selector = widgets.Dropdown(options=iris.feature_names, description='Variable:')
interact(update_boxplot, variable=variable_selector)
display(text_output)
```

I get:

[image]

I want to hide the previous selections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

from IPython.display import clear_output, display
from ipywidgets import Output, interact, widgets
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris


iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
df["species"] = iris.target_names[iris.target]

text_output = Output()


def update_boxplot(variable):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    with text_output:
        display(widgets.Label(value=f"Variable: {variable}"))

    fig = px.box(
        df,
        x="species",
        y=variable,
        title=f"Boxplot of {variable}",
        labels={"species": "Species", variable: variable},
    )
    fig.show()


variable_selector = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=iris.feature_names, description="Variable:"
)
_ = interact(update_boxplot, variable=variable_selector)
```

---

**Explanation**

<sub>The last line in your code was at fault for your highlighted printing issue (`display(text_output)`). Indeed - that line was displaying the text output from your ipywidget.</sub>

<sub>The only other change I made was assigning the `interact` function to a nondescript underscore variable '`_`' ([a common convention when wanting to ignore some variable](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/role-underscore-python)). This prevents other extraneous text (in this case, the function descriptor for `interact` [i.e., "`<function __main__.update_boxplot(variable)>`"]) from printing to the output below the cell in the Jupyter Notebook.</sub>